# Embedding the output of a server script inside another HTML page

Tags: php, html, svg

I have a php script (generator.php) which generates certain HTML/XML/SVG depending on various conditions. I want to embed the output of this script in my homepage (home.php)

eg. Let generator.php always generate an SVG document (complete with SVG NS and DTD). Now I want to embed this generated image in the output of home.php

I have tried `<object>`, `<embed>` and `<iframe>`. None seem to work. Does anybody know how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use either:

1. [include file on the PHP side.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) So on the home.php page simply include the generator.php file at the point where you want the output.

OR

2. [Use AJAX on the client side.](http://www.w3schools.com/Ajax/ajax_example.asp) On home.php when the page loads in the browser you can make a simple AJAX call to generator.php and dispay the output at the desired place on the page.

Update (Considering the comment below): Did you try this:

```
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="generator.php" width="300" height="200"></object>
```

for the SVG?

Comment: This would work only if the output of the included php file (generator.php) is HTML. If the output is SVG, it will not be rendered!

Comment: As long as you send the proper mimetype for the SVG output [Content-type: "image/svg+xml"] then it should work fine with <object>, <iframe> or <embed>. You may have to make sure that the browsers don't cache the result, e.g using a no-cache header or by changing the url so that it includes a random/unique part (generator.php?foo=asdb323423) or something like that.

Comment: It worked by sending the MIME type as an HTTP header from PHP using the header() call. Thanks for pointing out that it was a MIME type problem :)